# Logging/Tracing-Lib for .Net

Tags: .net, logging, nlog

i need to swap from Log4Net to some other logging library that has some build-in functionality for at least these requirements:

- FileLogging (text)
- Archiving by size and date (no archive should ever be deleted)
- Archiving to zip/compressed file
- Possibility to configure archiving in a way, to have only one zip file per day

I did try some of the major libraries like NLog and SmartInspect but none offer functions to move archived/rolled files to a zip file.

For Log4Net i did just implement that functionality myself but for some new project my customer does not want to use Log4Net...

Would it be possible to extend NLog with NLog.Extended to do this?
Or does someone know an other lib that allready has this "features" (free or commercial)?

Thanks in advance

Rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rene - [Serilog](http://serilog.net)'s free and has a very simple model for plugging in sinks. I'd recommend simply copying the source of the `RollingFileSink` class from its GitHub repository, and adding a few lines of code to zip the "outgoing" file on roll.

Plugging a custom sink like that back in is easy:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Sink(new ZippedRollingFileSink("C:\\Logs\\myapp-{Date}.txt"))
    .CreateLogger();
```